# How to calculate total value in gridview android

Tags: android, string, gridview, integer

I have an onclick gridview. When I clicked the item in the gridview, it will showing the name and the price of the item.

In my code, Deskripsi means the name of the item that I clicked and harga means the price of the item that I clicked.

```
public void deskripsi(){
    gdviewgal.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String str = adapter.imagelist.get(position).getNama();
            int hrg = adapter.imagelist.get(position).getHarga();
            deskripsi.append(str + ", ");
            harga.append(hrg);
        }
    });
}
```

There is another textview that can showing total harga that means total cost. Previously I have tried to change like this, but I got error

```
String str = adapter.imagelist.get(position).getNama();
            int hrg = adapter.imagelist.get(position).getHarga();
            deskripsi.append(str + ", ");
            harga.append(hrg + " + ");
            int a = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(harga));
            total.setText(a);
```

I don't know how to adding all the price and showing the total price.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

what is the error? if you want to run all the components to verify one by one if hace a value you can use method  "instance of" like this

```
ArrayList<View> viewList = getViews();
   Iterator<View> iterator = viewList.iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext() && viewList != null) {
      View view = iterator.next();
  if(view instanceof TextView){
       //verify if the object have any value to convert to double or any type to sum
  }
}
```

maybe you can show what's the error(pthoto, capture) to can help you.